# how to get the number of click in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently writing a unity c# script, the main idea is when I click on some part of the model, the part will be highlighted, and now I want it to return to original state by clicking it again. When I click on the same part at the 3rd time, it should be highlighted again.

I don't know how to achieve it inside Update() method, because every click costs several frames and I cannot recognize which frame is the 2nd click, 3rd click, etc.

Is there any way to recognize the number of clicks without considering frames in unity?

```
 void Update(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit)){
                bone = hit.collider.transform;
                if (boneList.Contains(bone) != true)
                {
                    /* if the part is not chosen before, add it to the list and highlight all elements in the list */
                    boneList.Add(bone);
                    Highlight(boneList);
                }/*cannot delete the element chosen repetitively*/
    }
}}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()` (or `Input.GetMouseButtonUp()`) rather than `Input.GetMouseButton()`?

Comment: @squill25 It's fine, Programmer's answer looks a lot more comprehensive than the time I can currently put into an answer. As long as the question gets solved. =P

Answer (score 4):

You are so close. The `else` statement should be added to your code. Your logic should be like this:

```
if(List contains clickedObject){
    Remove clickedObject from List
    UnHighlight the clickedObject
}else{
    Add clickedObject to List
    Highlight the clickedObject
}
```

Also, like [Serlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587447/how-to-get-the-number-of-click-in-unity-c-sharp#comment72307285_42587447) mentioned, you have to use `GetMouseButtonDown` instead of `GetMouseButton` since `GetMouseButtonDown` is called once when key is pressed but `GetMouseButton` is called every frame while the key is down.

The final code should look like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
        {
            bone = hit.collider.transform;


            if (boneList.Contains(bone))
            {
                //Object Clicked is already in List. Remove it from the List then UnHighlight it
                boneList.Remove(bone);
                UnHighlight(boneList);
            }
            else
            {
                //Object Clicked is not in List. Add it to the List then Highlight it
                boneList.Add(bone);
                Highlight(boneList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to write the `UnHighlight` function which basically restores the passed in GameObject/Transform to its default state.